# How to return False one of the two if statement is false?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following if statement:

```
item_y = item[1]
item_target_y = item_target[1]
item_x = item[0]
item_target_x = item_target[0]

if (item_y + 1) != item_target_y or (item_y - 1) != item_target_y or (item_x + 1) != item_target_x or (item_y - 1) != item_target_x:
    return False
```

my function takes two arguments, where each argument represent a tuple. If I conduct a unitary test, this should return true

```
assert game((3,3),(4,4)) == True
```

as well as

```
assert game((3,3),(2,2)) == True
```

the item can only move diagonally up or downwards

My issue issue is that I am only able to satisfy one condition at a time and not both

My function is

```
   def game(item, item_target):
      return bool
```

Comment: Could you provide your code for the `game()` function? It looks like a fragment which is not reproducible.

Comment: why `game((3,3),(4,4))` should return true instead of `False`?

Comment: I provided the code at the bottom. I am trying to return a bool, where if item is able to make the move to item_target

Comment: @AlwaysSunny because when (3,3) moves diagonally on the board, it's next position is (4,4) or (2,4) if it moves down, it's next position is (2,2)..

Comment: wait wait, I thought def game(item, item_target): contains above statements of item[1] or item_target[1]

Comment: @Always Sunny item, and item_target are tuples. I then extract their x and y value for comparaison

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you are simply not telling it to return True otherwise.So the code should be something like this :

```
item_y = item[1]
item_target_y = item_target[1]
item_x = item[0]
item_target_x = item_target[0]

return (( (item_y + 1) == item_target_y or (item_y - 1) == item_target_y )
    and ( (item_x + 1) == item_target_x or (item_y - 1) == item_target_x ))
```

EDIT :
I read your code and this is the function that you actually want.

Comment: Thank you what changes did you make? aside from the return True

Comment: the other changes are actually comparing two things: if the item values for y are -1 or +1 to the target value AND if the item values for x are -1 or +1 to the target x values. You see the AND and OR changes that I did in the function.

Comment: Check the edit that was just suggested by @Kimmel and approved, where we return directly the condition and it actually gives True or False in the return statement. It makes the code cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Fahd gave a correct answer. I'm just going to provide an alternative using the `all()` builtin function:

```
items = (item, item_target)
return all(items[i][j] - 1 == items[-(i - 1)][j]
           or items[i][j] + 1 == items[-(i - 1)][j]
           for i in range(1, -1, -1) for j in range(2))
```

It checks that all the elements of `items` (`item` and `item_target` tuples) match the condition: Each position's value of one tuple must be equal to the same position's value of the other tuple ± 1.